# why foreach doesn't work inside my highchart and when i splet the array it works?

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts, spring-restcontroller

this is the ajax method to get data from restcontroller

```
function get_data() {
var datas = '';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/tower/getDataTower',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: datas,
    success: function(datas) {
        oneTowerChart(datas); //put data into highchart
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a, b, c + 'error ******')
    }

});
```

}

i put data into highchart using this method

dsi[0],dsi[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38yzu.png) // here is the probleme when i use a foreach it's doesn't work but like that it's working

console.log(dsi) // this is the data i want to put into my chart its an array you find the
result in a picture

```
function oneTowerChart(datas) {
var dateNow = Date.now();
var day = dateNow.getUTCDate();
var month = dateNow.getUTCMonth();
var year = dateNow.getUTCFullYear();

console.log(datas)
var dsi = [];

datas.forEach(
    data => {
            switch(data.uetype){
                case "During service":
                    console.log(data.uetype);
                    break;
                case "Out of service":
                    console.log(data.uetype);
                    break;
                case "During service (internal root cause)":
                    dsi.push([Date.UTC(data.uestart.year, (data.uestart.monthOfYear-1) , data.uestart.dayOfMonth, data.uestart.hourOfDay,data.uestart.minuteOfHour),10]);
                    break;
                case "During service (external root cause)":
                    console.log(data.uetype);
                    break;
                case "Out of service (internal or external root cause)":
                    console.log(data.uetype);
                    break;
            }
        }
)

console.log(dsi) // this is the data i want to put into my chart its an array you find the 
                    result in a picture
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Highcharts.chart('graphOnDemand',{
    
    //highchart code...

    series: [{
        name: 'during service internal',
        data: [
            dsi[0],dsi[1] // here is the probleme when i use a foreach it's doesn't work but like that it's working
            ],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#BFBFBF'],
                [1, '#E5E5E5']
            ]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'during service external',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2021, 6, 14, 12, 05), 2],

        ],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#2E75B6'],
                [1, '#B5CEE5']
            ]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'out of service internal or external',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2021, 5, 1, 12, 05), 5],

        ],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#FFC000'],
                [1, '#FFE8A2']
            ]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'during service',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2021, 4, 17, 12, 05), 29.9],

        ],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#ED7D31'],
                [1, '#F9D0B4']
            ]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'out of service',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2021, 5, 3, 12, 05), 29.9],

        ],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#C00000'],
                [1, '#E49595']
            ]
        }
    }]
});
```

}

[image: console.log(dsi)]

Answer (score 1):

The variable `dsi` is local to the `oneTowerChart` function and as such, is [out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) when you try to access it later.  One way you can fix it is to make `dsi` a global variable by moving its definition outside of your function

```
var dsi = [];
function oneTowerChart(datas) {
  // your code, without var dsi = [];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but i found a solution for that thanks

Answer (score 0):

i modified my code like that and it works

```
Highcharts.chart('graphOnDemand',{

//highchart code...

series: [{
    name: 'during service internal',
    data:dsi,

    //code...
```